# Backbone collection not updated with model from REST response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, rest, backbone.js

I have an backbone app, back-end is Node/Express.js with a REST API.  The application allows users to create new entries, and used to have only client side validation to cleanse and update certain fields.  However, entries could be created via the REST API (not client) and I wanted a consistent and easy to maintain validation procedure, I moved the validation to the server.  It was at this point that I realized my backbone implementation was not working as I understood it would.

Take this code, to add a new model.

```
this.collection.add(time);
time.save();
```

My understanding (as it turns out probably wrong) was that the collection would update, sync with the REST API via the model URL property.  So any server side updates would be synchronized with the backbone model, as the REST API returns the updated model (with validation updates).  Unless I'm doing something wrong, it doesn't work this way?

I've now updated my code (above) so it looks like this, waiting on the ajax `.done` response and then adding the update model to the collection.

```
time.save()
  .done(function (model) {
    self.collection.add(model);
  });
```

It works, but is this the best way to do  it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [create](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) method to add the new model within a collection and save it to the server.

```
time.create(model);
```

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks!  Not sure how I missed that one, glaringly obvious now.